# Sharing a Singleton Instance Across Multiple Nodes in the Same Process in ROS 2

Tags: ros2, ros2-control, ros2-launch

I am working on a robotic system using ROS 2, where I have implemented a singleton class in C++ to handle CAN interface communications. This singleton is used by two nodes; `ros2_control_node`, which belongs to the controller_manager package, and another node `sensors_publisher` I implemented to retrieve sensor data from CAN and publish them. The same launch file starts both nodes.

**The problem:** When launching the system, I observed that these nodes operate in separate processes, meaning they don't share the singleton instance as intended.

**The question:** How can I ensure that those two nodes are spawned within the same process to share the same singleton for communication in a ROS 2 environment?

Answer (score 1):

To run multiple nodes in one process, you can just instantiate them in the same `main()` and add them to an executor, see e.g. the [minimal composition example](https://github.com/ros2/examples/blob/1d97c4fc7445554f6f85f63305d424fc017212a0/rclcpp/composition/minimal_composition/src/composed.cpp#L25-L29).

There are different types of executors, e.g. `SingleThreadedExecutor`, `MultiThreadedExecutor`, `StaticSingleThreadedExecutor`, `EventExecutor`, etc but that is somewhat out of the scope of this question. See the [documentation on executors](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Concepts/Intermediate/About-Executors.html) as well as the [examples](https://github.com/ros2/examples/tree/rolling/rclcpp).

An alternative solution is mentioned in following tutorial: [Composing multiple nodes in a single proces](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Tutorials/Intermediate/Composition.html), and in the corresponding how-to guide: [Using ROS 2 launch to launch composable nodes](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/How-To-Guides/Launching-composable-nodes.html).

Comment: Thank you, @JRTG! Your reply is very relevant, but there is a challenge. I do not think I have much control over ros2_control_node because it is instantiated using the hardware_interface of ros2_control. There is no `main()` like writing the node from scratch. Please tell me if my explanation is unclear. If you got what I meant, please feel free to share your thoughts.

Comment: You could instantiate the controller_manager in a custom node, without using ros2_control_node.
But I think you should give the hardware_components a try, see the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the sense of ros2_control framework, you should:

- write a hardware_component implementing your CAN communication and export state and command interfaces all at once. This is a single thread from the ressource_manager being part of the CM.
- write/use a controller claiming the necessary interfaces (state+command)
- write a sensor broadcaster claiming the exported state interfaces and publishing them as topics (basically, your `sensors_publisher`)

Comment: Thanks, @Christoph! I have implemented those points. I have 1 and 2 handled by the hardware_compoenet but separated 3 in its own node for clean design. Now, I end up with two nodes. How can I make the two nodes operate in a single process? This is my question.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible at all. Why do you think your design would be cleaner?

Maybe you could write two hardware_components, as we [demonstrate here](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/ros2_control_demos/example_5/doc/userdoc.html).

Comment: Thanks for sharing that, Cristoph! I think my sensors_publisher should be implemented using the `hardware_interface::SensorInterface`. I will give it a try.

Comment: I implemented the `hardware_interface::BaseInterface<hardware_interface::SensorInterface>` for reading the robot's multiple range sensors. Every sensor reading is just one value expressing distance from the obstacle. The error I got is **Loader for controller 'sensors_broadcaster' not found.** Does this mean my plugin is not detected? Please notice I am using ROS 2 Foxy due to the robot's available OS. I would appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: So you implemented a SensorInterface like in [this example](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos/blob/master/example_5/hardware/include/ros2_control_demo_example_5/external_rrbot_force_torque_sensor.hpp)? 
Your error is from a controller, which controller do you want to spawn? What does  `ros2 control list_hardware_components` tell you, was your SensorInterface loaded correctly?

Comment: Thank you, Christoph. Excuse me, the holiday delayed my response. From the Foxy branch, I used the rrbot_with_sensors example to start simple. I added a sensor component for ToF sensors. I am getting the state_interfaces as expected with `ros2 control list_hardware_interfaces`. The problem is the tof_sensors data are published on the topic `dynamic_joint_states` and mixed with joint states, which is not intuitive. Is there a way to get the tof_sensor states published on their own topic using this interface?

Comment: Here is the [rrbot_system_with_sensor example](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos/blob/foxy/ros2_control_demo_hardware/include/ros2_control_demo_hardware/rrbot_system_with_sensor.hpp) I referred to in the previous comment. I would greatly appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: This question is not related to your initial question, please open a new one to help future users finding the correct answers.